# GroupCommand Extra Param (record.data.)

Tags: .net, extjs, command, ext.net

When I click in my GroupCommand, I get this error:

```
"ReferenceError: record is not defined"
```

This is the code:

```
<DirectEvents>
    <GroupCommand OnEvent="GrdHorarios_GroupCommand">
        <EventMask ShowMask="true" MinDelay="2000" Msg="Carregando" />
        <ExtraParams>
            <ext:Parameter Value="record.data.IDBDRElenco" Mode="Raw" Name="elencoId">
            </ext:Parameter>
            <ext:Parameter Value="command" Mode="Raw" Name="commandName">
            </ext:Parameter>
        </ExtraParams>
    </GroupCommand>
</DirectEvents>
```

Can I use the `record.data.anyfield` in a `GroupCommand` or exists a other way?

Comment: in a GroupCommand you can use a records[0].data.anyfield

...

Thanks..

Comment: post as answer+accept....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GroupCommand event fires in the context of the clicked group of records. So, a "record" parameter would not make a lot of sense. So, an array of records which the clicked group consist of is passed into a GroupCommand listener. Well, as @[assoline](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2140299/assoline) stated.